# Neo4j stuck when create relation with big data

Tags: neo4j, cypher, bigdata

i'm using this cypher query to create relationship between two nodes in Neo4j

```
MATCH (first:FIRSTNODE)
with first
MATCH (second:SECONDNODE)
WHERE first.ID = second.ID
CREATE (first)-[:RELATION]->(second)
```

**first** has 100.000 of nodes and **second** has 1.100.000 nodes.

I have imported the csv file and then i've created index of the two tables; but when i try to run the query with the relation neo4j got stuck and stop working.
I noticed that the cpu usage goes at 100% when this happens.

I'm working with an cpu of 8x4.0Ghz and 10Gb of ram and an SSD.

Do you know something that can help me to resolve this problem?

## EDIT 1:

Using [apoc.periodic.commit](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_apoc_periodic_commit) it works. But if then i run a second query like this:

```
call apoc.periodic.commit("
    MATCH (third:THIRDNODE)
    WHERE NOT (third)-[:RELATION2]->()
    WITH third LIMIT {limit}
    MATCH (second:SECONDNODE)
    WHERE third.ID = second.ID2
    CREATE (third)-[:RELATION2]->(second)
    RETURN count(*)
", {limit:10000})
```

it got stuck again

Comment: I believe you forgot the match with a `first` node, right?

Comment: nope, it's another relation between a second and a third one. At the end relation should be like this: (first)-[:RELATION]->(second) & (third)-[:RELATION2]->(second). To do the RELATION2 i have to run another query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using [apoc.periodic.commit](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_apoc_periodic_commit) from [APOC Procedures](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/). The docs about this procedure says:

> **apoc.periodic.commit(statement,params)** - runs the given statement in
>   separate transactions until it returns 0

Install APOC Procedures and try it:

```
call apoc.periodic.commit("
    MATCH (first:FIRSTNODE), 
    WHERE NOT (first)-[:RELATION]->()
    WITH first LIMIT {limit}
    MATCH (second:SECONDNODE)
    WHERE first.ID = second.ID
    CREATE (first)-[:RELATION]->(second)
    RETURN count(*)
", {limit:10000})
```

Remember to install APOC procedures according the version of Neo4j you are using. Take a look in the [version compatibility matrix](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_version_compatibility_matrix).

Comment: For the first relation query it works, but if i have to do another relation on the same session it no works anymore

Comment: @NicolaCurrò please, can you explain a bit more about your problem? I did not underdand.